# How to get version from an abaqus output database file?

Tags: finite-element-method, abaqus

I want to read some data from an .odb file, but when I open it using the C++ API I always get this error message:

> file.odb is from a more recent release of Abaqus.
>
> The current Abaqus installation must be upgraded before this output database can be opened.

I also tried a newer version of Abaqus, but I got the same error. Is there a way to get the version from an odb file so that I don't have to try all Abaqus versions?

My Abaqus version is 6.14-1.

Comment: Version 6.14 is five years old now. If you are going to upgrade, why do you want to upgrade to another out-of-date version instead of the latest one?

Comment: The problem is that I can't just upgrade to the newest version. I would need to buy a new license.